# My instruments sound muffled on consumer gear and radio, even though it sounds okay in the studio? What can I do to fix it and why is it like this?

Tags: audio-recording, mastering, radio

I have been working on my new single but I feel like it could have a brighter more professional finish. To me, it sounds like there is a problem with the dynamics. The drums and the brass sections seem muffled I wonder what can be done to fix it. I have topped and tailed it so its tighter and in better time on the newer one I have here in front of me but it doesn't sound as professional as John Newmans "will you love me again" for instance, I have been working with top notch engineers but to no avail, why? It sounds okay in the studio on top notch speakers, but when I listen to it through radio or on other systems, it sounds too muffled.

What can I do to make my single sound brighter and more professional without the instruments muffled?  How can I account for the loss of fidelity associated with radio or consumer audio gear?

You can hear it [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEGj5zJFnyM).

Comment: you can contact me on george@theroaringforties.com

Comment: You might have passed the red _ahem_ "nazi" boxes quicker by actually making your question meet the required standards. It doesn't, at the moment! – You can upload your single to e.g. [SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/), [link to it](http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com/questions/190/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled), and ask about something specific in the way it sounds right now and what you don't like. Then we might be able to actually help you.

Comment: This isn't really a question, but more of a discussion.  If you can post your file somewhere publically accessible and then ask a question about how to get it to sound like you want with a description of how you'd like it to sound and a link to the file, then we can probably be much more helpful.  As leftaroundabout said, the little red boxes were telling you it didn't meet standards because it didn't and doesn't currently meet standards.

Comment: Stack Exchange is focused on questions and answers that are generally useful and, while I think this could potentially be made to fit, it needs some work to focus on what the problem is you are experiencing and what you are looking for an answer on how to fix.  The more general you can make the problem (so that it will be useful to others) the better.  If you simply need a critique, it might be best to try jumping in [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/733/audio-video-chat) to discuss it once you have sufficient reputation to do so.

Comment: Oh, and please don't take my comments as a criticism or beating the new guy, it's just the purpose of this site is a bit different from most sites you might be used to.  It takes a little getting use to, but helps make it a much more useful and accessible source of information.

Comment: Be prepared, if you do post your song somewhere that folk on this site can access, you might get a few more pointers than what you bargained for. It's not a warning but taste/fashion/age plays a part in potentially mastering a song and these are not easily quanifiable objectives.

Comment: Hear it here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEGj5zJFnyM I want to know if its a frequency problem that takes away the dynamics, the drumsand the brass sections seem muffled I wonder if it's being cancelled out. I'm looking for some one who can take the elements and fix it, soon, as we are re releasing it in november and need it ready, I have topped and tailed it so its tighter and in better time  on the newer one i have here in front of me but doesn't sound as professional as john newmans "will you love me again" for instance, iI have been working with top notch engineers but to no avail, why?

Comment: "COMMENTS MAY ONLY BE EDITED FOR FIVE MINUTES"  Please help me soon because I am not going to last another hour on this dreadfully policed forum

Comment: Is this in America? I don't mean to be rude but wow

Comment: This is not a forum where you scream for quick help, it's a Q&A site where we gather up information supposed to be useful on the long run. Hence the policies, which are empirically chosen to solicit high-quality content.

Comment: ok ok, calm down

Comment: In music production there are 2 important steps called mixing and mastering. If you are not satisfied with results after those two steps consider paying a n engineer to do it for you and that's how artists/producers get professional sound. Dont get me wrong, you can do it by yourself if you know how to and at times it takes longer to master the art or mixing or mastering.

Comment: @georgepatterson - clearly you are upset.  It isn't that we are overly police like, it's just that this isn't a forum.  If you take a look at the [About](http://avp.stackexchange.com/about) page, it does a pretty good job of explaining what the purpose of the site is.  I hope that the site can be a valuable resource to you and if you have questions that are useful to the general public, then we are here to help with answering those questions.

Comment: A request for a review of a particular track without any clarification in your question about what you are trying to fix beyond a simple "sound more professional" isn't really enough for anyone else to find the question when they have a similar problem though, which is why it was put on hold as unclear what you are asking.  If you can edit the question to ask a more specific question about the sound (using the edit button), then it will automatically be put in the queue for reopening and we might be able to help.

Comment: The key is to find a way to ask your question so that it can be found by others with a similar problem in the future so that they can also benefit from the answer.  Note that this also isn't someplace to find people to do a task for you.  We can help advise you on what you need to do or have done, but we're specifically not a jobs board.

Comment: @georgepatterson - I've edited your question based on the new information you provided in the comments to try and make it more generally useful.  As a quick answer however, the only thing I really noticed about it is that the vocals aren't very well blended with the music.  The reason that the instruments are "muffled" is because of the way it was mastered and was intentional.  It's fairly common to give music of that style a more aged feeling.

Comment: Recorders of the time couldn't reproduce the fidelity of what we have now, so the music tended to take on that kind of a sound and it was very well pulled off.  If you don't want that sound, I would suggest going back to whoever did your mastering and let them know you want a cleaner sound and they should be able to fix you up just fine.  Personally, I don't think it is a problem though.  I would just try to get the vocals blended with it a little better.

Comment: thank you. I turn swing Jazz into something palatable for younger audiences as an introduction to Jazz swing, I am looking for the formula, every studio linked to the big companies like sony, arista, universal etc do it with out a problem, my engineers can't, i show them a highly produced song and they cannot reproduce that clarity or dynamic. does any one here know the formula?

Comment: I'm still unlcear what the question is, and I'm not sure how the OP is defining "muffled". "muffled" compared to what? Personally, I think that this is a good engineering question, but needs more clarity about specifically what you're trying to achieve, using objective language and descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into "Multiband Compression".

Also, you should mix-down and master on a variety of speakers from pro- to consumer-grade and adjust the EQ etcetera so that it sounds good across all of them (not just the studio speakers, those are for finding minute flaws).

Answer (score 1):

Get a set of NS-10's... But more to the point (to elaborate on the post above),

One of the more deceiving issues in a recording studio is that they tend to have some of the best speakers in the world installed in some of the best listening spaces ever made. This is all great until you consider the fact that (especially today with the iPod etc) most music is consumed in a less than optimal setting. A mix may sound great on your ADAM monitors but by the time it hits ear buds it is not quite right. I would advise actually mixing on some less than optimal devices. If you can get a final pre-production mix to sound good on iPod headphones in the studio, it will sound good on your really nice speakers too (or at least it should). I mention the NS-10's as they are one of the more famous studio monitors. They are actually not very good speakers for all intensive purposes but legend has it that "If it sounds good on the NS-10's it will sound good anywhere" Thus engineers liked to mix on them which in turn forced a good end result. Basically you account for the loss in fidelity by creating that loss from the get go.